# Phrase structure "Zum" + noun + verb?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification

Considering the following examples:

1. Ich brauche etwas **zum Lesen**.
2. Ich hoffe, **die Prüfung zu bestehen**.

The 1st example refers to the whole action as a noun (**zum Lesen** = zu + dem + Lesen). If adding an object for the verb after **zu**, one ends up with 2nd example (**die Prüfung zu bestehen**). Those structures are very common; however, I just saw the example below:

3. Die hat dann was **zum Geld verdienen** gesucht.

I thought it should have been "**Die hat dann (et)was gesucht, Geld zu verdienen**". However, this new structure is more compact; I don't know how it is grammatically called. What is it then? (I tried "Infinitivgruppen/Infinitivsätze", but couldn't find similar examples).

Can I apply the same structure, e.g. "***Ich brauche eine Lampe zum Buch lesen***" (of course, I can also express it in a familiar way: "***Ich brauche eine Lampe, (um) ein Buch zu lesen***"), or this special "**zum Geld verdienen**" structure is fixed and should be learned by heart?

In addition, it looks to me, **das Geld verdienen** can be used as a whole noun group. Can I make a sentence like "***Das Geld verdienen ist zeitaufwendig***"?

Lastly, based on my limited understanding, the above structure in german language is similar to those in english:

4. **To play online-game** is time-consuming.
5. **Playing online-game** is time-consuming. / **Online-game playing** is time consuming.

Is that correct?

If so, in english, we can sense a *possibly* slight difference between those: in 4., the activity hasn't yet happened (maybe I'm planning on playing games in the future); in 5. the activity is already taking place (I'm playing online-game at this moment, or at present). Could we *subtly* express this slight difference in german? E.g "**Geld zu verdienen ist zeitaufwendig**" and "**Das Geld verdienen ist zeitaufwendig**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Die hat dann was *<s>zum Geld verdienen</s> zum Geldverdienen* gesucht.
> - Ich brauche eine Lampe *<s>zum Bücher lesen</s> zum Bücherlesen*.
>
>   <sup>(*Buchlesen* is also correct, but *Bücherlesen* seems more idiomatic to me.)</sup>

The pattern is the same as in your first example sentence, where [*Lesen*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lesen) is a noun that results from [nominalizing](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung) the verb *lesen*:

> 1. Ich brauche etwas *zum Lesen*.

The tricky thing with multipart verb phrases, such as *Geld verdienen* or *Bücher lesen*, is that the result of nominalization is a [compound noun](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)):

- (das) [*Geldverdienen*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Geldverdienen)  =  (das) *Geld*  +  (das) *Verdienen*
- (das) *Bücherverdienen*  =  (die) *Bücher*  +  (das) *Lesen*

(Here, *Verdienen* and *Lesen* are nouns that result from nominalizing the corresponding verbs.) Notice that compound nouns are written as one word and must be capitalized in German, that is, "*zum Geld verdienen*" and "*zum Bücher lesen*" are grammatically not correct.

Another possibility is to use an infinitive with *zu* like in your second example sentence:

> 2. Ich hoffe, die *Prüfung zu bestehen*.

If you reformulate the above sentences accordingly, you get:

> - Die hat dann was gesucht, um *Geld zu verdienen*.
> - Ich brauche eine Lampe, um *Bücher zu lesen*.

Comment: On Google, the phrase "zum Geld verdienen" returned 461k results while "zum Geldverdienen" onle gave 97.4k.

Comment: It's not about grammar but orthography.

Comment: @RHa, whether something is a verb or a noun is a matter of grammar, isn't it?

Comment: @JoyfulPanda, this is a telling example that shows why you shouldn't trust Google.

Comment: I just read this sentence in a german textbook: "Zeit opfern heißt Zeit investieren."